# Почему проваливается картинка при задании в vh и %?

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

1. Почему, когда я у `.img` задаю `width: 100vh`, тумбочка проваливается в изображении?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. А когда в процентах - `width: 100%` - то все нормально?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Но, если оставить в процентах, то тогда картинка обрезается на маленьком разрешении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. А при `width: 100vw` норм.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    slideSpeed: 9000,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
    center: true,
    dots: true,
    responsiveClass: true,
    smartSpeed: 400,
    margin: 0,
    responsive: {
      0: { items: 1, margin: 0 },
      800: { items: 1 },
      1100: { items: 1 },
      2000: { items: 1 }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Light', arial;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 310px;
  position: relative;
}

/*section main*/
.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 190px;
  left: 80px;
  z-index: 99;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.info-text h2 {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

.info-text p {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', arial;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 56px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

.info-button {
  background-color: #b36060;
  font-family: Lora;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #fefefe;
  width: 208px;
  height: 43px;
}

/*sidebar*/
.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 310px;
  background: #5b5858 url(../img/menu_bg.jpg) center repeat;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.logo {
  width: 245px;
  height: 76px;
  border: 3px solid rgba(197, 120, 64, 0.65);
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.logo h1 {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 44px;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f4f4f4;
}

.logo span {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-15%, 80%);
  background: url(../img/menu_bg.jpg);
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 14.2px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.desc p {
  text-align: justify;
  letter-spacing: 1.4px;
  width: 245px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #aaa9a9;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.menu-main {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.menu-main ul li:nth-child(2):before {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  content: '1';
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  background: url(../img/rectangle.svg) center no-repeat;
  float: right;
}

.menu-main ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f7f7f7;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.menu-main ul li a:hover {
  color: #ff7200;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.menu-main li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #686464;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.menu-sub ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #bdbdbd;
}

.menu-sub ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.contact a.phone {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fefefe;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.contact a.request {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #c57c40;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #c57c40;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.contact a.request:hover {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

/*Slider*/
.img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  min-width: 100vw;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/clear.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/adaptive.css">
  <link href="https://allfont.ru/allfont.css?fonts=open-sans-light" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://allfont.ru/allfont.css?fonts=noto-sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/7dca09e227fdfe16908cebb4244589e4?family=Georgia" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <script src="owl.carousel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>Сияние - Декор центр</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="top-content">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="#">
            <h1>сияние</h1>
            <span>декор центр</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="desc">
          <p>Интернет-магазин отделочных материалов и дизайна</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="menu-main">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">каталог товаров</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">новости и акции</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">наши услуги</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">портфолио</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">блог</a></li>
            <li><a href="">контакты</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-sub">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Отзывы о нас</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Доставка и оплата</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Дизайнеры</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="contact">
        <a href="tel:+78005118909" class="phone">+7 (4822) 648-080</a>
        <a href="#" class="request">Заказать звонок</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="gallery">
        <div class="owl-carousel">
          <div class="img" style="background-image: url(img/bg-1.jpg);" class="div"></div>
          <div class="img" style="background-image: url(img/bg-2.jpg);" class="div"></div>
          <div class="img" style="background-image: url(img/bg-3.jpg);" class="div"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <div class="info-text">
          <h2>Декоративные покрытия</h2>
          <p>от лучших производителей</p>
        </div>
        <button class="info-button">Подробнее <span>&rarr;</span> </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Вот как быть? Ставить в медиа-запросах только 100vw?

Comment: `width: 100vh` vh - это опечатка?

Comment: 100% считается от контейнера, а 100vw - от viewport. Т.е. у вас не тумбочка проваливается, а полшкафа уехали вправо на ширину боковой панели слева.

Comment: width: 100vh опечатка. Конечно же там должно стоять 100vw